# How to drag and drop between two (or more) wxListCtrl (wxGTK)?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to organize a wxListCtrl-derived control (`xList`) which support DnD between items (`LC_REPORT` view). So, I catch BEGIN_DRAG event

```
Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG,
        (wxObjectEventFunction)&xList::OnBeginDrag
       );
```

and `OnBeginDrag` function is designed in a way to catch mouse motion and mouse left button up events for each instance of `xList` (`list`):

```
list->Connect(wxEVT_MOTION,
              wxMouseEventHandler(xList::OnMoveDrag)
             );
list->Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,
              wxMouseEventHandler(xList::OnEndDrag)
             );
```

(and `OnEndDrag` disconnect them all). When I have single `xList` instance (one panel) it works perfectly, but when I have two it looks like motion and left-up events are caught only for the panel I start dragging from: I can DnD inside single panel, but when I drag mouse from one panel to another it still acts like `xList::OnMoveDrag` is still working for first panel. What I am missing to?

Is `wxEVT_MOTION` handled for each widget separately? If so, why program acts like this. If not, why it is always handled for widget I start dragging from, not the last connected one?

Here is a sample code (as far simple as I could reach) to show what's happening:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <vector>

class xList;

// class to store group of xList to DnD between
class DnDxList
   {public:
       void BeginDrag ();
       void EndDrag ();
       void AddList (xList* l) {list.push_back (l); }; // register new xList object
    private:
       std::vector<xList*> list;
   };


class xList: public wxListCtrl
   {public:
       xList (DnDxList& dnd,
              wxWindow *parent,
              wxWindowID winid = wxID_ANY,
              const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
              const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize,
              long style = wxLC_ICON,
              const wxValidator &validator = wxDefaultValidator,
              const wxString &name = wxListCtrlNameStr
             );
       virtual ~xList () {};
       void OnBeginDrag(wxListEvent& event);
       void OnEndDrag(wxMouseEvent& event);
       void OnMoveDrag(wxMouseEvent& event);

       DnDxList& dndsource; // keep reference to common DnDxList object
   };


void DnDxList::BeginDrag () // connect motion and left-up events for all lists in group
   {for (std::vector<xList*>::const_iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
        {(*i)->Connect(wxEVT_MOTION,
                           wxMouseEventHandler(xList::OnMoveDrag)
                      );
         (*i)->Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,
                       wxMouseEventHandler(xList::OnEndDrag)
                      );
        }
   };

void DnDxList::EndDrag () // disconnect all
   {for (std::vector<xList*>::const_iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); i++)
        {(*i)->Disconnect(wxEVT_MOTION,
                          wxMouseEventHandler(xList::OnMoveDrag)
                         );
         (*i)->Disconnect(wxEVT_LEFT_UP,
                          wxMouseEventHandler(xList::OnEndDrag)
                         );
        }
   }




xList::xList (DnDxList& dnd,
              wxWindow *parent,
              wxWindowID winid,
              const wxPoint& pos,
              const wxSize& size,
              long style,
              const wxValidator &validator,
              const wxString &name
             ): wxListCtrl (parent, winid, pos, size, style, validator, name),
                dndsource (dnd)
   {Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG,
            (wxObjectEventFunction)&xList::OnBeginDrag
           );
    dndsource.AddList (this);
   };


void xList::OnBeginDrag(wxListEvent& event) // begin drag
   {SetCursor(wxCursor(wxCURSOR_HAND));
    dndsource.BeginDrag();
   }

void xList::OnMoveDrag(wxMouseEvent& event) 
   {std::cout << "Movie: " << this << std::endl;  // to show the object for which the move event is called for
   }

void xList::OnEndDrag(wxMouseEvent& event) 
   {std::cout << "End: " << this << std::endl;
    dndsource.EndDrag();
    SetCursor(wxCursor(*wxSTANDARD_CURSOR));
   }


class xFrame: public wxFrame
   {
    public:
        xFrame (const wxString& title,
                const wxPoint& pos,
                const wxSize& size
               );
        ~xFrame () { }
    private:

        void OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event);
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();

        DnDxList* dndxlist;
        xList* lp;
        xList* rp;
        wxPanel* panel;
   };

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(xFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(wxID_EXIT, xFrame::OnExit)
END_EVENT_TABLE()


xFrame::xFrame(const wxString& title,
               const wxPoint& pos,
               const wxSize& size
              ): wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size)
  {
   panel = new wxPanel(this);
   wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

   // create common DnDxList
   dndxlist = new DnDxList(); 
   // create two panels
   lp = new xList (*dndxlist,
                   panel,
                   wxID_ANY,
                   wxDefaultPosition,
                   wxDefaultSize,
                   wxLC_REPORT | wxLC_SINGLE_SEL
                  );
   rp = new xList (*dndxlist,
                   panel,
                   wxID_ANY,
                   wxDefaultPosition,
                   wxDefaultSize,
                   wxLC_REPORT | wxLC_SINGLE_SEL
                  );

   // some contents
   lp->InsertColumn(0, _("A"));
   lp->InsertColumn(1, _("B"));
   lp->InsertColumn(2, _("C"));
   lp->InsertColumn(3, _("D"));

   lp->SetColumnWidth(0, 100);
   lp->SetColumnWidth(1, 100);
   lp->SetColumnWidth(2, 100);
   lp->SetColumnWidth(3, 100);


   for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {lp->InsertItem(i, 1);
       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
          {wxString s;
           s << _("lp [") << i << _(", ") << j << _("]");
           lp->SetItem (i, j, s);
          }
      }

   rp->InsertColumn(0, _("A"));
   rp->InsertColumn(1, _("B"));
   rp->InsertColumn(2, _("C"));
   rp->InsertColumn(3, _("D"));

   rp->SetColumnWidth(0, 100);
   rp->SetColumnWidth(1, 100);
   rp->SetColumnWidth(2, 100);
   rp->SetColumnWidth(3, 100);


   for (long i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {rp->InsertItem(i, 1);
       for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
          {wxString s;
           s << _("rp [") << i << _(", ") << j << _("]");
           rp->SetItem (i, j, s);
          }
      }

   sizer->Add(lp,1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 10);
   sizer->Add(rp,1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 10);
   panel->SetSizer(sizer);


  }

void xFrame::OnExit(wxCommandEvent& event)
  {
   Close( true );
  }


class xApp: public wxApp
   {
    public:
       virtual bool OnInit();
   };

IMPLEMENT_APP(xApp);


bool xApp::OnInit()
   {
    xFrame *frame = new xFrame(_("Frame"), wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(450, 340) );
    frame->Show(true);
    return true;
   }
```

Looking into console output one can find that mouse motion event and mouse left-up event always calls methods for the same object, where dragging starts from, not the object mouse is actually on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wxListCtrl`-specific drag events are indeed only meant to be used for dragging the items inside the same control. To drag and drop stuff between different controls, or even between different applications, you need to use the general `wxDragSource` and `wxDropTarget` classes.

Comment: OK, thank you, but I wonder if `wxDragSource` and `wxDropTarget` would let me to do some action during moving process since I'd like to highlight a place where user going to drop, i.e. space between lines of table where the dragging content will be inserted. Because if I just catch `EVT_MOTIOIN` result would be the same.

Comment: You can use [wxDropTarget::OnDragOver()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_drop_target.html#a1e4f4c8f0a4ce7c6a731007e82788652) for this.